# Blank POST with nginx upload module and chunked upload

Tags: nginx, upload, http-post

I am using the [nginx upload module](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUploadModule) to accept large uploads for a PHP application.  I have configured nginx following [this blog post](http://bclennox.com/extremely-large-file-uploads-with-nginx-passenger-rails-and-jquery) (modified for my needs).

Here is (the applicable portion of) my nginx configuration:

```
server {

    # [ ... ]

    location /upload {
        set $upload_field_name "file";
        upload_pass /index.php;
        upload_store /home/example/websites/example.com/storage/uploads 1;
        upload_resumable on;
        upload_max_file_size 0;
        upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name[filename] "$upload_file_name";
        upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name[path] "$upload_tmp_path";
        upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name[content_type] "$upload_content_type";
        upload_aggregate_form_field $upload_field_name[size] "$upload_file_size";
        upload_pass_args on;
        upload_cleanup 400-599;
        client_max_body_size 200M;
    }
}
```

In the client side JavaScript, I am using 8MB chunks.

With this configuration, I am able to upload any file that is one chunk or smaller.  However, when I try to upload any file that is more than one chunk, the response I get from the server for each intermediate chunk is blank, and the final chunk triggers the call to the PHP application without any incoming `POST` data.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that [@Brandan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1133199/brandan)'s blog post actually leaves out one important directive:

```
upload_state_store /tmp;
```

I added that and now everything works as expected.